# SharePoint Office 365 Video Portal - Trending Video's title are appearing as DispForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, video, office-365-video-portal

SharePoint Office 365 Video Portal > Trending Video's Title is appearing as DispForm.aspx, However in "All Videos" are title is coming fine.

We have tried to upload videos using Code and manual, getting this title issue in both the cases.
[image]

Also similar issue have been noticed in "You might also like" section

[image]

Comment: can you share the code snippet that you are using ?

Comment: @Gautam, when we are trying to upload manually also, getting same title issue...